# Execute a function after a time of delay base on if conditon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a logic code like this with JavaScripts:

```
if(a===b)
//wait 5 s
wait(5);
//recheck a===b
if a continue === b
--->do something
if not
do nothing
```

Can we do it with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Please explain this logic `if a continue === b`...

Comment: @palaѕн: I just want to check if a continue equal to b, so I will do something(because I don't know the value of a and b change or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but you need to look at it slightly differently - it's not a linear sequence of steps, because there's no wait or sleep command. Instead, you can schedule a function to be run after a specified delay.

So your steps actually look like:

```
if (a===b) {
    // set function X to happen in 5 seconds
}

function X() {
    if (a == b) { // still equal
        // do something
    }
}
```

In actual code, that could look like the following:

```
function checkIt() {
    if (a == b) {
        doSomething();
    }
}

if (a == b) {
    setTimeout(checkIt, 5000);
}
```

...or the slightly more condensed version:

```
if (a == b) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (a == b) doSomething();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: thank u,I am looking for it, because I am fixing for others bug and I don't have time to track what functions will change the value of a and b,so I just want to wait 5s and reload another function.

Answer (score 1):

With Javascript, you would use timeouts for this.

```
if(a===b){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    if(a===b){//Recheck a === b
      do_something();
    }
  }, 5000);//Wait 5000 milliseconds before executing this function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for [**`.delay()`**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) in jQuery

> Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

Seems [**`setTimeOut()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) fits for you.

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
```

Comment: @Tuong something wrong in your logic.  this means are try to make it as a recursive?  because you are trying to check the a===b even after the conditional if.  Try to clarify your question

Comment: It is not a loop here, the function will change the value of a or b